# Webmethod return datatable with root element is missing

Tags: xml, vb.net, soap, datatable, asmx

I have a webmethod that does a sql query and returns a datatable. When I try to access via php I get returned an error that a root element is missing. I think that is what brings together all the results that are returned to me. How do I create this root element? What's wrong with my code?

```
<WebMethod(ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Xml)>
Public Function GetComponents(password As String) As DataTable

    Dim dt As New DataTable

    con.Open()

    StrSql = "Select Fridge FROM Component"

    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(StrSql, pricon)

    dt.TableName = "Components"


    da.Fill(dt)

   con.Close()



    Return dt

End Function
```

Comment: 1) You are calling `con.Open()` and `con.Close()` for no reason. Also, `da.Fill(dt)` will open and close `pricon` for you.

Comment: 2) What does the returned XML look like?

Comment: Th documentelement is nothing. Its the problem...

Comment: Are you saying that the SQL query returns no results and so the datatable is empty (or Nothing)?

Comment: No, the table returns multiple results and needs an element that groups all of them together. The problem is that webservice is not setting it.

Comment: Please edit the question to add a small example of the returned XML.